# Facebook Birthdays in Notification Centre

Tags: facebook

I'm a big fan of the Facebook integration in iOS 6, but it brings with it birthdays for all my Facebook contacts. I've figured out how to remove it from my calendar (de-select the calendar) but it still shows above my regular entries in notification centre. Any suggestions for getting rid of it?

Answer (score 2):

I disabled the contacts synchronization and I don't receive birthdays notification anymore. However I'm still able to receive other notifications (e.g. posts, pictures, ...)

Comment: That's what I have done, but I would love to have contacts sync again.

Comment: Is it a Facebook notification or a Calendar notification? Have you tried to turn of birthday alerts in Calendar preferences?

Comment: Where is that? I can't find it in mail contacts and calendars, quick google says it couldn't be done in iOS 5, changed in six?

Comment: Go to Settings -> Mail, Contacts, Calendars -> Default Alert Time -> Birthdays

Comment: I have that disabled already, it still shows in notification centre, above my regular calendars.

Comment: @iampearce In that case I' affraid that I've finished my solutions :(

Comment: Facebook integration seems really crappy in iOS6. Events are very buggy as well, even declined ones show up